# How to convert an a tag into a link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I turn the following Pinterest a tag into a rails link_to tag so that I could create the link dynamically

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url = "//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest"

link_to "Pinterest", url, { data: { pin_do: "buttonPin", pin_config: "none"} }
```

<strike>Note that you need to put quotes around 'pin-do' and 'pin-config' because of the dashes.</strike>
Update: Thanks to @Stefan, I've now learned that Rails automatically converts the underscores to hyphens in the data tags.

**Reference:**

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: You can use symbols with underscores: `data: { pin_do: "buttonPin", pin_config: "none"}`

Comment: Right, but from the question it appears that spuggy needs to use dashes.

Comment: Rails converts the underscores